For all $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ exists $q\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p(x)=(x^2+x)q''(x)+2xq'(x)+q(3)$
Show that for all $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ exists $q\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p(x)=(x^2+x)q''(x)+2xq'(x)+q(3)$.
the question does not mention if they are polynomials of finite or infinite degree, so my questions are

How is this proved in the case of finite degree polynomials?
Is it possible in the case where the polynomials are of infinite degree?

Thanks!

by definition the elements of $\mathbb R[x]$ have finite degree

The "polynomials of infinite degree" are called (formal) power series, the corresponding ring is usually denoted by $\Bbb R[[x]]$.

(1) Note that the RHS is linear in $q$. It would be sufficient to find $q_k$'s for a sequence of $p_k$'s with $\deg p_k = k$ ($k \ge 0$). If we take $q_k(x) = x^k$, the RHS is $(x^2+x)k(k-1)x^{k-2}+2xkx^{k-1}+3^k = k(k+1)x^k + \ldots$, which has the same degree as $q_k$ (consider the case $k = 0$ separately).
(2) $q(3)$ is not well defined for a general power series, so this equation does not make sense in the ring $\Bbb R[[x]]$ (without taking convergence into account). We can formally equate the coefficients and get $p_0 = q(3)$, $p_k = k(k+1)(q_k+q_{k+1})$ for $k \ge 1$. This system of linear equations $A\vec{q} = \vec{p}$ has an infinite upper-triangular matrix $A =$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&3&3^2&3^3&\cdots&\\\\
&2&2&&&\\\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&&\\\\
&&&k(k+1)&k(k+1)&\\\\
&&&&\ddots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix},$$
where the matrix and vectors are indexed starting from $0$.
Now, it is well known that an infinite upper triangular matrix over a field with nonzero elements on the diagonal is invertible, and the inverse is also upper triangular. Note that $A$ is "column finite" (each column has only a finite number, at most $3$, nonzero elements), but $A^{-1}$ likely wouldn't be, so $A^{-1}$ would not operate on column vectors "algebraically", only in the analytical sense.
It remains to find that inverse and investigate the set of sequences $\vec p$ for which every coefficient of $\vec q$ will converge.
